# What references to sadomasochism were there in Paradise Kiss?

Tags: paradise-kiss

[The Wikipedia page for Paradise Kiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_Kiss#Production) says (highlight from me):

> In many instances, Yazawa was concerned that taking the original material straight would distract casual viewers or worse drive them away. **Chief among these concerns was the handling of George's bisexual nature and interest in sadomasochism.** Yazawa agreed that the dialogue should reflect this, but that actual onscreen depictions (as can be found in the original manga) were to be avoided. However, Kobayashi felt this was not being entirely true to the character, so he **included a few hints of this side of George in the final episode.**

The fact that George was bisexual was stated in the very first episode, by George himself, after someone comments that they thought he was gay. However, I didn't catch any specific references to sadomasochism, neither in the last episode nor at any other point in the show.

What references is the Wikipedia page referring to?

Comment: Based on a quick search, TV Tropes listed this series as an example of [The Masochism Tango](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheMasochismTango). However, as I haven't seen the series, I can't say much about it, though I believe it's not about SM *play*...

Comment: Judging from the Wikipedia quote I wouldn't expect to _see_ any play in the anime, though I haven't read the manga so dunno if there were more overt references to it there. But I guess you make a good point that the Wikipedia article doesn't mention it's SM play, just SM in general... If no one's who's read the manga has some clarity, I might need to go through it myself to find out ;P

Comment: From what I remember, it should be referring to the character of George being sadistic, meaning he likes to tease the girl (rather than being sweet to her). It has nothing to do with sexual play using whips and candles.